# CORS error Angular 2 + Express Node

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

Front side(Angular 2)

```
public googlesearch(ev:Event){
    this.http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="+ev.target.value+"&types=establishment&key=AIzaSyAKdEt_dYbdPY-CFo0zie23E44XxTQc1n7").map(res => $.parseJSON(res)).subscribe( data => {
      this.predictions = data.predictions;
      console.log(this.predictions);
     },(error) =>{ 
       alert('Not able to get')
      } )


      }
```

Node (Express 4.14)

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

But I got CORS Error

> Failed to load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=loc&types=establishment&key=AIzaSyAKdEt_dYbdPY-CFo0zie23E44XxTQc1n8:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

And also did not get any request at npm console.

Answer (score 2):

That header has to be set by the target url server, `https://maps.googleapis.com/` in your case. setting header on your server will not help.

you can, however-

1. find an appropriate api that allows calls from browser.
2. implement a proxy to that url on your server and call it from browser.

Comment: Please explain it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an api for doing it in a cleaner way 
import the google map api via an script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initService"
    async defer></script>
```

And now declare an service from the autocomplete API

```
function initService(){
   autoService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
}
```

And in your event listener just do this

```
autoService.getQueryPredictions({ input: event.target.value }, displaySuggestions);
```

Follow for the full example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction

**EDIT**

**If you want to do it from your express application there is an npm for it**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleplaces

**Why are you getting an cors error after setting it up from your app.js**

Because in the front end you are calling the http service  get method with your the maps.google.com url so here in no way the browser will contact your server it will go directly to the google server trying to retrieve the content so your configuration in app.js is useless in this case unless your define a proxy in your angular.

Comment: And how can I use own different server services?

Comment: What do you want exactly ? you want express doing the request to the google api so you can from the angular controller call your own service and this one calling the googleApi

Comment: I want to know the reason, why after enabling cors at server app.js, I am not able to get response. Is there anything at front end which rejecting it?